# conceptual understanding of u-substitution in integrals: starting from the chain rule

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I get from 
$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}  f(u)du = \int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)dx \tag{8}$$ 
to
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u))g'(u)du \tag{9}$$

where $g^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $g$. E.g., solving $g^{-1}(u)=u=e^x$+1 for $x$ via $e^x=u-1$ we obtain $x=ln(u-1)=g(u)$.

I am trying to understand $u$-substitution for integration based on my old math notes and [Paul Dawkins' calculus cheat sheet](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/CheatSheets_Tables.aspx#CalcSheet). The equation labels above refer to the steps below.

*Please note*: There are many other posts here and elsewhere explaining $u$-substitution, I am interested in the specific step from (8) to (9). Happy also for pointers in case I overlooked this somewhere else!

---

Based on the chain rule

$$[f(g(x))]' = f'(x)g(x) \times g'(x) \tag{1} $$

we can write

$$[F(g(x))]' = f(g(x)) \times g'(x) \tag{2}$$

since $F'(x) = f(x)$.  Integrating both sides results in

$$ \int_a^b [F(g(x))]' dx = \int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x) dx \tag{3}$$

which simplifies to:

$$ [F(g(x))]_a^b= \int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x) dx \tag{4}$$

---

Building on (4), we can now demonstrate that 
 $$\int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x)  dx =  \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}  f(u)du \tag{5}$$

We already demonstrated that $\int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x) dx = [F(g(x))]_a^b$ in (4). Further expanding results in:

$$\int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x) dx = [F(g(x))]_a^b = F(g(b)) - F(g(a)) \tag{6}$$

Expanding $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}  f(u)du$ likewise results in:

$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)du = [F(u)]_{g(a)}^{g(b)}  = F(g(b)) - F(g(a)) \tag{7}$$

Thus, (6) = (7), and therefore (5) is true.

---

Switching sides in (5) gives:

$$  \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u)du  = \int_a^b f(g(x)) \times g'(x) dx \tag{8}$$

Now, how do I go from (8) to (9)? I feel like I am missing a step or two here.

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(u))g'(u)du \tag{9}$$

Comment: Just perform the substitution $u=g(x).$

Comment: Just to elaborate... apply $8$ to the right hand side of $9$ with $a=g^{-1}(a),$ $b=g^{-1}(b)$ and $g=g$ (I'm sorry for the horrible notation, but I wanted to fit with your exact choice of symbols).

Comment: @Allawonder, when substituting $u=g(x)$ in 8, would I not get $f(g(x))$ in the left of 9 instead of $f(x)$? Also, how would this change du and dx, and the bounds of the integrals?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou, not sure if I follow. I see that what you describe is happening from 8 to 9, but I don't see how.

Comment: @Flo Oh, I see what you mean now. Two secs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an abuse of notation, common with some types of analysts. This is the only way this makes sense. The author wanted simple limits on LHS, so they should have used other letters, or perhaps $A,B$ instead of using letters that have been already used for something else. Even if they wanted to continue using these letters, they should have given a warning. This shows they're a very bad author, and you shouldn't be wasting your money on their books.

Comment: Just to clarify, this was my attempt at combining notes from different instructors, so probably I mixed up something in between, rather than them ;) I added a note on notation in the question, but I think you were referring to the use of $a$ and $b$? From equatiosn 3 in my question it seems that they do refer to the same, so using the same letters would be ok, I would think?